# NServiceBus.Host.exe timeout and logging configuration - Configurable through NServiceBusHost.exe.config

Tags: c#, nservicebus, nservicebus3, nservicebus4

I have an issue with NServiceBusHost.exe.

Currently I am running a NServiceBusHost.exe as a windows services and am receiving timeout exceptions, as shown here:

Microsoft Service Trace Viewer output:

```
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.WindowsHost, NServiceBus.Host, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The specified network name is no longer available. This often indicates that the HTTP client has prematurely closed the underlying TCP connection.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.ListenerResponseHttpOutput.ListenerResponseOutputStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.SendReplyCore(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage9(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage8(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;CallbackGenerator&gt;b__2(AsyncCallback callback, IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.HandleParseIncomingMessage(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.AsyncCompletionWrapperCallback(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceAsyncResult.DoCallback(AsyncCallback callback, IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult.OnRead(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.HttpRequestStream.HttpRequestStreamAsyncResult.IOCompleted(HttpRequestStreamAsyncResult asyncResult, UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The specified network name is no longer available. This often indicates that the HTTP client has prematurely closed the underlying TCP connection. ---&gt; System.Net.HttpListenerException: The specified network name is no longer available
   at System.Net.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BytesReadPositionStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.ListenerResponseHttpOutput.ListenerResponseOutputStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.HttpListenerException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The specified network name is no longer available</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BytesReadPositionStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.ListenerResponseHttpOutput.ListenerResponseOutputStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Net.HttpListenerException (0x80004005): The specified network name is no longer available
   at System.Net.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BytesReadPositionStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.ListenerResponseHttpOutput.ListenerResponseOutputStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)</ExceptionString>
<NativeErrorCode>40</NativeErrorCode>
</InnerException>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
```

I am thinking to avoid this timeout exception from occurring, the timeout should be extended for the HTTP runtime.

Would anyone know if I am correct in thinking that HTTPRuntime configuration execution timeout in .NET (default in .NET 4.0 is 1:10 minutes) applies to the NServiceBusHost.exe?

Furthermore, I believe NServiceBusHost.exe is built on topshelf. Am I correct in thinking that log4net configuration could be applied to log any issues with the NServiceBusHost.exe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would anyone know if I am correct in thinking that HTTPRuntime configuration execution timeout in .NET (default in .NET 4.0 is 1:10 minutes) applies to the NServiceBusHost.exe?

Yes

> Furthermore, I believe NServiceBusHost.exe is built on topshelf. Am I correct in thinking that log4net configuration could be applied to log any issues with the NServiceBusHost.exe?

Yes definitely, see http://particular.net/articles/logging-in-nservicebus

Comment: With the NServiceBusHost.exe what configuration would allow me to increase the timeout to avoid the issue described